# Profiling GHC generated functions with `deriving` keyword

Tags: haskell, profiling, ghc

I am trying to optimize a Haskell program. In the profiler output, I see that a lot of time is spent inside `compare` and `==` functions. But, the GHC profiler doesn't tell me anything more than the module name of those functions. I guess these are the GHC generated functions using deriving `Eq` and `Ord`. I wonder if there is an easy way to pinpoint where the actual problem is. For instance, using
`{-# SCC "more-specific-name" #-}` for those functions.

Comment: `compare` and `==` **are already** the most specific names. They are the names of the methods from the `Ord` class. The `deriving` clause is an `instance` declaration where you defined the dictionary associated to an instance of the class. It seems like if you want to remove overloading from the code, but to do this you probably simply have to remove polymorphism from the code or use some `PRAGMA` for the compiler.

Comment: I don't want to remove overloading. I just want to find out if `==` is for type `A` or `B`. It could be easily done for hand written instances: set a different name for the implementation of each instance. But, since the implementation of the `Eq` is hidden from me (unless I implement it myself, not using the `deriving` keyword), I cannot use the `SCC` pragma.

Comment: By the way, `compare` and `==` are not the most specific names, I guess. They could be something like `A.compare` or `== of B`.

Comment: I haven't used it, and it looks like it requires Template Haskell, but [Data.Derive](https://www.cs.york.ac.uk/fp/darcs/derive/derive.htm) can spit out the code for derived instances, though possibly not the same code GHC generates.

Comment: There's a 3 year old open [GHC feature request](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7105) for this, which alas seems to have got little attention.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`-ddump-deriv`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/6.10.4/docs/html/users_guide/options-debugging.html) to dump out the code for the actual derived instances GHC generates, then grab the code and put it under your own explicitly defined functions.  Then explicitly derive the instances and point them at your functions.

Comment: This sounds to be a reasonable workaround, but I get weird field names such as `g2_ag0CR` and `b_aidSP` in the output. Optimization is also turned off with `-O0`, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Those are unique names GHC generates.  They're created there and only used there, so you can manually rename them to anything you want, like `mytype_compare` or `mytype_eq`.

Comment: All right, it seems that this approach is not so straight forward. I had to fix a lot of things manually, but I cannot figure out this one: there are a few calls to a `$con2tag_Foo` function, which I cannot find the definition in the dump. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Googling for `con2tag_Foo ghc` found me [this explanation](https://git.haskell.org/ghc.git/blob/08af5517f9057f999ef6db382b2b9b51aea215c9:/compiler/typecheck/TcGenDeriv.lhs#l1842). `con2tag_Foo :: Foo ... -> Int#` seems to be a function for converting a value of type `Foo ...` to an `Int#` tag for its constructor, numbered starting at 0, and is (or was, the file seems to have no HEAD version?) used to make more efficient instances of various classes.

Comment: `$con2tag` looks like it's deep internal GHC magic.  I think it represents an inaccessible ghc-internal function created along with the datatype.

Comment: How about a generic implementation of `Ord` similar to the one available for [`Eq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generic-deriving-1.5.0/docs/Generics-Deriving-Eq.html) or [`Hashable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashable-generics-1.1.8/docs/Data-Hashable-Generic.html)? Is there any `GOrd` implementation available?